# Javascript treating the number 0 as a blank string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, numbers

Noob problem.

In a Google Apps Script, I have an if statement that checks the value of a item in an array, which will either be a number, or blank:

```
var array = new Array();

array[0] = 1;

if (array[0] == '') {
 // this dos not execute
}

array[0] = 0;

if (array[0] == '') {
 // this executes
}
```

The contents of the second if statement get executed because it seems to be treating the 0 as a blank string. When I look at the value of array[0] in the debugger, it shows 0.0 (so it's definitely a number variable).

I first thought to use:

```
if (array[0] != 0 || array[0] == '')
```

but I can't use that because the actual if statement is a chain of OR operators like this:

```
if (array[0] == '' || array[1] == '' || array[2] == '')
```

and the other values in the array are actually strings, not numbers.

How do I write the if statement so that it differentiates between a 0 number value and no data (blank)?

Comment: try `array[0] === ''`

Comment: this may helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `===`

```
0 == ''  // true
0 === '' // false
```

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `0`, `''`, `false` are called falsy. If you use a `==` operator on two falsy values - it's always true. Unless you use `===` operator.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: That's not really why it works that way. The issue here is that when there's a number on one side of `==` and a string on the other, then the string is converted to a number before the comparison. The empty string is converted to 0 during that process, so the comparison made is `0 == 0`

Comment: Also `NaN`, `undefined` and `null`. But using `==` on  two falsey values is not always `true`.

Comment: For example, `NaN == 0` is `false`, though both those values are "falsy".

Comment: These are all false: `NaN == NaN` `NaN == 0` `NaN == undefined` `NaN == null` `NaN == ""` `NaN == false` `undefined == 0` `undefined == ""` `undefined == false` `null == 0` `null == ""` `null == false`

Comment: And sometimes comparing a falsey value to a truthy value using `==` is `true`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `===`

**For Example :**

> var array = new Array();
>
> array[0] = 0;
>
> if (array[0] === '') {  // this doesn't execute }
>
> if (array[0] == '') {  // this executes }